# Class inheritance and sticky attributes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes

Some python class inheritance is having some unanticipated consequences, namely "sticky" attributes that I would have expected to be reset.

A simplified scenario, that still demonstrates what's happening:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, headers={}):
        self.headers = headers

class Bar(Foo):

    def __init__(self, headers={}):
        super().__init__(headers=headers)
```

```

If I instantiate an instance of `Bar`, I can see `.headers` are blank.  Then edit `bar.headers`, and see they are modified.  But *then* instantiate another instance of `Bar`, and unexpectedly the `.headers` is still modified:

```
In [39]: bar = Bar()

In [40]: bar.headers
Out[40]: {}

In [41]: bar.headers['baz'] = True

In [44]: goober = Bar()

In [45]: goober.headers
Out[45]: {'baz': True}
```

Is there a better pattern for this kind of inheritance?  Otherwise, everything else is working nicely and as expected.

Comment: This has **nothing to do with inheritance**, rather, you are using a mutable default argument.

Comment: In short, the `headers` default argument is always the same dictionary.

Comment: Duly noted, thanks for such a quick response.